# Error: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing one hybrid iOS app using *cordova*. While installing one cordova plugin I am getting the following error

> Error: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.

Config.xml is there in my project. I couldn't get feasible solution.Someone posted like to remove platform and again add platform.I do not want to take risk by removing platform as it is existing project.

Comment: Removing platform is not a risk provided you dont have any file changes done directly inside the platform.

Comment: which plugin are you installing?

Comment: plugin is :cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics

Comment: @Gandhi ,

is it a feasible solution removing the platform and again adding?

Comment: @ChiranjitJasu It does no harm provided you have all you changes up to date in the root www project folder

Comment: OH GOD, removing platform removed my widget

Comment: same problem here. There is a native plugin in my project that required tons of config settings in .xcodeproj and I really don't want to re-do them again. However I have faced the same error message when trying to update the cordova version.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove `$(SRCROOT)/` before your app name in buildSettings section for debug and release mode in `project.pbxproj` which locates in `platforms/ios/YourAppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. You can open it with a text editor such as "Sublime Text".

E.g., there are two lines with same content like this:

```
INFOPLIST_FILE = "$(SRCROOT)/YourAppName/YourAppName-Info.plist";
```

Just change it to

```
INFOPLIST_FILE = "YourAppName/YourAppName-Info.plist";
```